# How to pass a complex JSON object through VB.net to call Rest API

Tags: json, rest, api

I have a Rest API which I have to call from my vb.net code.
In the Postman I pass the arguments in the Body as follows:

```
{
    "Search" : 
    {
        "EmpName" : "Rachel",
        "EmpID" : "1100320"

    },
    "IncludeAttributes" : ["EmpId", "EmpName","Department","Salary","ManagerId"]
}
```

My problem is that I am not sure how can I pass this kind of parameter through my call from VB.Net call.
Here is what I have tried:

```
Dim searchParameters = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        searchParameters.Add("EmpName", "Rachel")
        searchParameters.Add("EmpID", "1100320")
        Dim jsonSearchParameters = 
                        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchParameters)
        Dim stringContent = New StringContent(jsonSearchParameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```

And now I am clueless of how to pass IncludeAttributes part in the same object.
Any help please?

Comment: hint - try `New Dictionary(Of String, New Dictionary(Of String, String))()` for the `Search` key

Comment: I understand - but if you see its a kind of heterogeneous data. Search can be Dictionary of Dictionary, but what will be Include Attributes? To explain what I mean here is the pseudo code, which will definitely not work: Dim SearchAttributes As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
            SearchAttributes.Add("Search", searchParameters)
            SearchAttributes.Add("IncludeAttributes","[""DiskSetId"", ""Repository"",""ClaimNumber"",""Id"",""Category""]"" )

Comment: What about `Dictionary(Of String, Object)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cricket_007 suggests a Dictionary(Of String, Object) would work:

```
Dim search = New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {
    {"EmpName", "Rachel"},
    {"EmpID", "1100320"}
}

Dim searchParameters = New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
    {"Search", search},
    {"IncludeAttributes", New String() {"EmpId", "EmpName", "Department", "Salary", "ManagerId"}}
}

Dim jsonSearchParameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchParameters)
Dim stringContent = New StringContent(jsonSearchParameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```

Alternatively, create a class to hold the parameters:

```
Public Class Search
    Public Property EmpName As String
    Public Property EmpID As String
End Class

Public Class SearchParameters
    Public Property Search As Search
    Public Property IncludeAttributes As String()
End Class
```

and then fill the classes in with the appropriate data:

```
Dim search = New Search With
    {
        .EmpName = "Rachel",
        .EmpID = "1100320"
    }

Dim searchParameters = New SearchParameters With
    {
        .Search = search,
        .IncludeAttributes = New String() {"EmpId", "EmpName", "Department", "Salary", "ManagerId"}
    }

Dim jsonSearchParameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(searchParameters)
Dim stringContent = New StringContent(jsonSearchParameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```

Comment: thank you "theduck". Class idea is really a good one too. I went ahead and worked with Dictionary of string, object.

Answer (score 1):

As cricket_007 suggested I tried Dictionary of string, object and it worked like a charm. For any one else coming here with the similar issue here is my piece of code, which worked:

```
Dim searchParameters = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
searchParameters.Add("EmpId", EmpId)
searchParameters.Add("EmpName", "Rachel")

Dim includeAttributes() As String = {"EmpId", "Name", "Dept", "Manager", "Salary"}

Dim SearchAttributes As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
SearchAttributes.Add("Search", searchParameters)
SearchAttributes.Add("IncludeAttributes", includeAttributes)

Dim jsonSearchParameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SearchAttributes)
```